# How do I get the leaf from a cls string in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to store class names in a dict to use later:

```
class ray_base(type):
   def __call__(cls, name='unamed', *args, **kwargs):
      ff.factory_dict[str(cls)]=cls
      return super().__call__(name)
```

However, when I look at the `factory_dict` I see that the `str(cls)` gives a messier answer than I expected:

```
"<class 'tests.test_base_classes.base_classes_TestCase.other_object'>" = {ray_base} <class 'tests.test_base_classes.base_classes_TestCase.other_object'>
```

I would like to only have `other_object` as the key in the `dict`.

Is there a way to get this leaf type name other than splitting the string and pulling out the name?

Comment: `cls.__name__`?

Comment: D'oh!  I forgot about  `__name__`

Answer (score 2):

As @thebjorn said above. The answer was simple.

`cls.__name__` contains the leaf name.